# How to pass JSON data to react-native-maps-super-cluster

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using this library called [React Native Super Cluster](https://github.com/novalabio/react-native-maps-super-cluster) to render clustered markers on the map. How can I pass JSON data that is fetched from API and saved in a redux state to the library's `data` prop?

The `data` props objects must have an attribute `location`. The data that I'm trying to feed the prop has that attribute but still, map can't render markers.
I tried to experiment with the simple local array it worked without problems. And when I render all API locations' markers with [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps) they get displayed on the map too.

Here is example response from API:

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -122,
        37
      ]
    },
]
```

The way I'm doing it probably wrong:

```
<ClusteredMapView
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  data={this.props.stations}
  renderMarker={this.renderMarker.bind(this)}
  renderCluster={this.renderCluster.bind(this)}
  initialRegion={INIT_REGION}
/>
```

`renderMarker` and `renderCluster` functions won't get called because data props received invalid data type.

Comment: could you please share a bit of your code in order to see your work around?

Comment: @HelmerBarcos added, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering my own question.**

After a bit of research and digging into the library's source code I found that `location` attribute must be provided in `location: {lat, long}` form. In other words, it should be directly accessed by the library. Therefore, I extracted each value from the JSON object and assigned it to `location`.

I'm not sure how efficient is this, please add your own answer if it's more elegant and straightforward than this:

```
  _convertPoints(data) {
    const results = {
      type: 'MapCollection',
      features: []
    };
    data.map(value => {
      array = {
        value,
        location: {
          latitude: value.location.coordinates[1],
          longitude: value.location.coordinates[0]
        }
      };
      results.features.push(array);
    });
    return results.features;
  }
```

**Render**:

```
  render() {
    const data = this._convertPoints(this.props.stations);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ClusteredMapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          data={data}
          renderMarker={this.renderMarker.bind(this)}
          renderCluster={this.renderCluster.bind(this)}
          initialRegion={INIT_REGION}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

After those manipulations, it seems to be working. Hopefully when I customize map everything will be okay :)